# Change arguments that start up with JFS driver on linux

Tags: linux, driver

I am more common with the QNX os and I could change the arguments for the ide driver on startup.  I wanted to change the arguments that get started in a linux kernel for the jfs filesystem which mounts a flash card.  I can't seem to find a good web source for this information but I am sure I am not "googling" it right.

What are the different options available for the jfs/ide driver and where do I change them for the current running driver?

Thank you and I apologize this isn't exactly programming but this site always produces great answers when I ask a programming question so I figure it might help here too.

Answer (score 0):

ok, i finally found out it is defined in the /etc/fstab file.  Now I just need to find out what options are available and best for a compact flash card.

Answer (score 0):

Options for most filesystems are shown in the "mount" manpage.

The ata driver may also have various tunables. You can probably change these in real time with "hdparm".

Some options might be filesystem create time options, in which case mkfs will document them.

See the relevant man pages.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass options to jfs, you need to pass them as part of kernel boot
line, which is specified in your grub.conf or lilo.conf file.  You can find the supported
options in the Documentation/ directory of the kernel source, or the jfs source itself.

As for the recommended mount options, you need to look at the mount(8) man page.
I would recommend *noatime,nodirtime* at a mininum.  The default is *atime*, which
causes the file inode to be updated everytime you look at a file.